# Reconstructing a cubic form

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algorithms, computational-mathematics, multilinear-algebra

I am given a number of points $n_1,\ldots,n_\ell$ from an integer binary cubic form $ax^3+bx^2y+cxy^2+ey^3$ (without any information on what $x,y$ generated them). Can I reconstruct the form $(a,b,c,e)$ and if so, how?`

Comment: When you say "I am given a number of points..." what exactly do you mean?

Comment: nothing if the letters are real numbers. If all are integers, a little. Trygve Nagell put a lot of effort into representations of $1$ by integer binary cubic forms. Briefly presented in Mordell, Diophantine Equations.

Comment: @WillJagy Integers, yes. Edited.

Comment: @KReiser I have an explicit finite set of integers.

Comment: Charles, regardless, the outcome of this resembles that for binary quadratic forms. There are infinitely may binary cubics that are integer equivalent to your original, where equaivalent means linear change of variables with determinant $\pm 1,$  so that the inverse map is alos integral. You may then thing about your preferred "reduced" forms, those being representatives.

Comment: @WillJagy So, how to find this class of forms, or at least a representative from it, given an assortment of points on it?

Comment: @WillJagy Or, alternatively, prove that there is no quadruple $(a,b,c,e)$ on which all the points lie.